# Grunt file not building CSS file (SASS): Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - undefined

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, sass, gruntjs, visual-studio-2017

I have a Grunt file, that should build my CSS file. When I run the task in the Task Runner (Visual Studio), I get below error:

> Running "sass:dist" (sass) task Errno::ENOENT: No such file or
>   directory @ rb_sysopen - undefined   Use --trace for backtrace.
>   Warning: Exited with error code 1 Use --force to continue. Aborted
>   due to warnings. Process terminated with code 6.

My Grunt file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed'
                },
                files: {
                    '/css/styles.css': '/css/sass/styles.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: ['css/sass/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                },
            },
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

My directory:

[image]

I use Visual Studio 2017 and have a standard ASP.NET Core project.

I read a bit, and it seems it could be the SASS cache. However, when I run the `rm .sass-cache/ -R` command, I get

```
rm: cannot remove '.sass-cache/': No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there's confusion over what path you're starting from.  I believe grunt runs from the project root, and `wwwroot` is a subfolder of that.  Either prefix your paths in the grunt file with `wwwroot/`, or consider moving your .scss files out of `wwwroot` entirely, since they aren't intended to be served.  They can go under the project root, and you can have grunt copy the .css outputs into `wwwroot` where they belong.

Comment: And you're of course right. Thanks for your further comments on how it shold be, instead of the "hack" of prefixing. Thanks!